# Jasmine $HTTP requests with mock data

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Im trying to test $http requests and no matter what I do I cant seem to get it to work. I have a factory that holds the 4 request type GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

Im trying to test the response from a get request but my scope variable that is assigned the response in the controller is giving an error or undefined = the response from the get request.

The factory code is as follows:

```
app.factory('requestService', ['$http', function ($http) {
// reusable requests
return {
    //reuable get request
    getRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: url
        });
    },
    //reuable post request
    postRequest: function (url, data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: url
        });
    },
    //reuable put request
    putRequest: function (url, data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: data,
            url: url
        });
    },
    //reuable delete request
    deleteRequest: function (url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: url
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

The following is in the controller.

```
    //get the teams
    $scope.getTeams = function(){
    requestService.getRequest('https:.../teams').then(function (response) {
        $scope.teams = response;
    });
}
$scope.getTeams();
```

Jasmine code:

```
describe('Controller Test', function() {
var $rootScope, controller;

//Tell the $httpBackend to respond with our mock object
var teamsResponse = {// Teams Data //};

beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp')
});    
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, $http) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller;
    controller('Controller', {$scope: $scope});

    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    $httpBackend.whenGET('https:...../teams').respond(200, teamsResponse);

}));

it('should load a list of teams', function() {
    $scope.getTeams();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($scope.teams).toBe(teamsResponse);
});
});
```

The error I get is:

Expected undefined to be {// Teams Data //}

Comment: Where's the code you're testing? What's the exact error? 'error or undefined = the response from the get request' isn't clear enough.

Comment: @estus EDITED the question content

Comment: I don't see right away why it's undefined and not even sure that it's even possible considering provided data, but the problem is that you're doing functional/integration test. A proper unit-test is twofold. In controller test you mock requestService. And in service test you mock http requests. The objective of this is to test code line by line and narrow down the problem to a single line of code when there's any.

Comment: Also, it's preferable to use expect...respond in `it` instead of when...respond in `beforeEach`, see the remark on strict vs loose https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#request-expectations-vs-backend-definitions

Comment: The code creates two get requests: one when the controller is instantiated and again in the `it` block. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("Testing Common Get JSON Service", function () {

    var service, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector,$rootScope) {
        service = $injector.get('CommonService');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        successCallback = jasmine.createSpy();
        errorCallback = jasmine.createSpy();

        $httpBackend.when('GET', getFlightIncidentLookupUrl).respond(getFlightIncidentLookup);
        successCallback();
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('test getServiceJSON works fine and calls a GET method', function () {
        service.getServiceJSON(getFlightIncidentLookupUrl).then(function(response) {
            expect(response.data.incidentLookup.length).toEqual(1);
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });


});
```

This worked for me . here CommonService is a service in Angular js which calls a get method. I got the response correctly.